# How to make bootstrap navbar right-pulled items align correctly into navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

What I currently have:

https://jsfiddle.net/st589n9j/show/

It works perfectly fine on desktop view, I want it as it is for desktop view.

But for mobile view it is being shown as:

[image]

and what I want is:

[image]

I tried various things with moving navbar div elements around, but it only got messier and I am not able to fix it.

The way I was looking forward to was such that user icon doesnt get merged into collapsible menu, but if it can be done with merging it in menu by removing user icon and auto-expanding dropdown items then I am open to that option.

I tried to do it as per fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nomis/n9KtL/1/

But on doing this, the collapsible menu doesnt collapse the same.

Sorry if it seems stupid, I have very less designing knowledge.

HTML:

Toggle navigation
        
        
        
      
      Toolbox

```
<div class="navbar-header pull-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="/users/id" title="Profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/logout" title="Logout">Logout </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
```

Fiddle for the code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/st589n9j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an example code at **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/YGzmZz?editors=1100)**

I hope this solves your issue.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Toolbox</a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav navbar-header navbar-profile  pull-right">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown ">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="/users/id" title="Profile">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/logout" title="Logout">Logout </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<!-- /.navbar -->
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-profile ul.nav > li > a {
  color: #777;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.navbar-profile ul.nav > li .dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-profile {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    right: 80px;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: This looks good Jyoti, but user icon turned blue and clicking it, the dropdown is going off the screen. Can that be fixed? This mostly solves the problem though thanks a lot!

Comment: Thats the css issue can be fixed very easily with little padding, margin and positioning. I hope you will figure it out.

Comment: Dont know if its the most elegant way but I fixed it by adding style "color:#777; margin-top: 5px;" and by adding class pull-right to its li. Thanks for your help. Do let me know if you believe something better can be done :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122589/discussion-between-mohitc-and-jyoti-pathania).

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the collapse class and remove the button which shows up when you resize it to mobile view.

If you want to keep your menu items inline then you can override the navbar class in bootstrap by adding your own class or you can make changes into bootstrap's css file.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Toolbox</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
                <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a href="/users/id" title="Profile">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="/logout" title="Logout">Logout </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav><!-- /.navbar -->
```

Comment: You removed the whole user icon items on mobile view, how will a user access those items on mobile then? Also I do not want collapsible menu to auto collapse on mobile view